# How to stop Facebook mobile in-app browser cache on WordPress

Tags: plugins, cache, facebook, cloudflare

we needed to create briefed posts and publish, then in a few hours we update the post content. post content gets updates on web and the end user can see the updated content. but if a user opens up the post in facebook via its in-app browser, then come back later to see the updated content, they will see the same post as before.

if another user first checks the post after it has been updated, they will see the updated content. but wont see the updated post if they are rechecking it after opening it before updating.

this sounds like caching. if it is from the server side, the browser would have not shown the updated content. how do we stop facebook from caching posts in its in-app browser?

Comment: This is a question you’d need to ask Facebook, or at least something you’d need to check in their documentation. It’s not really related to WordPress. At the very least I’d ask at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: this isn't something you can fix from the WordPress end if you want to keep the same URLs, this is a facebook issue that needs a facebook resolution. It's very likely that the only solution is to tell users to go into the settings page and clear the cache, otherwise, don't rely on updating post content to do what you're doing, create new posts when you have new content so they have different URLs

Comment: If you're not already I'd look into generating Cache-Control HTTP headers or similar when your page is in the initial state specifying a short lifetime or when you're expecting to update the page. No idea if Facebook would respect those though.